# SQL Server - create stored procedure that runs several stored procedures sequentially

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm not sure if this is possible but if so, my scenario would be about as simple as they come.  Assuming I have 6 stored procedures called:

```
dbo.SyncSources
dbo.SyncData
dbo.UpdateStatistics
dbo.TruncateSourceTable
dbo.ValidateData
dbo.SearchData
```

None of them require any variables to be input, they simply need to be executed in the order in which they appear above.  Can I create one stored procedure that will run all of them, sequentially?  Keep in mind that some of the middle ones in that list take several hours to run.  Also, this is on an Azure Cloud database, so SQL Server Agent is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: What have you *tried*???  This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: i don't see why you can't? 1 SP that calls all those sps.. does not need a sql agent.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
create procedure OneProcedureTorunThemAll

as
begin tran
exec dbo.SyncSources
exec dbo.SyncData
exec ...
commit
```

it could be nice to catch errors, verify return values, etc.

Comment: Thank you Horaciux, it's always nice to know that the majority of the people here are not like certain people that can be found in the above comments.  I will try this.

Comment: See my edit. If you need to ensure that all of them should finish ok, you can wrap it in a transaction.