# How to execute stored procedures by Order in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a stored procedure which calls other stored procedures but I don't want to execute them at the same time. Stored procedure #1 execution takes time so when it finishes stored procedure #2 will start to execute.

How can I do this?

```
EXEC SP1;
--wait for SP1 to finish its job
EXEC SP2;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013312/sql-server-create-stored-procedure-that-runs-several-stored-procedures-sequent/44013708#44013708

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80184/run-multiple-stored-procedures-in-sequence

Comment: It works like that by default. There's nothing you have to change in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as

```
EXEC SP1;
GO
EXEC SP2;
GO
```

Comment: Not even GO statements are needed.

Comment: You can't even use `GO` inside a stored procedure, which is the context of the question - "a stored procedure which calls other stored procedures"

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like :

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
exec( @sp1)
exec(@sp2)
exec(@sp3)
COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 (Validate it )
ROLLBACK (rollback to sp where you want to )
END CATCH
```